How to config Firebase without google-services.json, but by code and control Firebase crash analysis on/off dynamically?
There is a project that needs to implement the dynamic configuration of relevant parameters during Firebase initialization, and enable Firebase's error log analysis function after the configuration is completed. How to extract the content in the "google-services.json" file for the dynamic initialization of Firebase?
I hope to have specific Java code for dynamically initializing Firebase and enabling Firebase log reporting.

I found that I can report key events normally by directly putting the downloaded google-services.json file under the Android project. However, I want to configure Firebase dynamically by setting FirebaseOptions. How should I handle it?
